# Invalid publishSettings file for regestring with Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service

In order to connect and debug a node.js program on Azure websites, I need to use a publishSettings file. When I download one from the Azure management console, and try to import it I get the following:

```
c:\>azure account import "MyServices.azurewebsites.net.PublishSettings"
info:    Executing command account import
error:   Invalid publishSettings file. Use "azure account download" to download publishing credentials.
info:    Error information has been recorded to azure.err
error:   account import command failed
```

When I try to use the "azure account download" command, it opens a browser window, and then gives me a 500 error from the azure management system.

Same things happen when I try to do this from the Azure PowerShell commands.

Thanks

Comment: I encounter the same issue using the xplat-cli v0.8.2 on my mac.

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat confusing, but the publishSettings file you're trying to use is a specific publish settings for your Azure Website while you actually need the publish settings for your Azure account.

You can get it from here: https://windows.azure.com/download/publishprofile.aspx

`azure account download` is also correct, not sure why you get a 500.

Comment: @Amir Apple, thanks for your answer. As mentioned, I tried both the link above, the 'azure account download' command and the powershell Get-AzurePublishSettingsFile. All three do the same thing, point me to the URL above, and give me a 500 error. I am dead in the water. Any other ideas?

Comment: Try using an InPrivate/incognito browser tab to login to the Azure portal, once there try the https://windows.azure.com/download/publishprofile.aspx url.

Comment: That was a good idea, but it did not work. Same result 500 error. Is there a way to download this file from the management console somehow?

Comment: Is this issue still happening to you?

Comment: Yes, still an open issue. I am dead in the water! Cannot debug my app so I am flying blind.

Comment: Can you provide your site's name?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of xplat-cli and PowerShell are you using?

"MyServices.azurewebsites.net.PublishSettings" Seems like the website publish profile which is not the subscription publish settings file we need here. But the command should direct you to the right place to get them.

Can you try go to https://management.windowsazure.com/publishsettings/index directly and get the file? This is the URI we use in our command.

It would be great if you can let me know what is the URI xplat-cli or PowerShell directs you to.

Thanks.

Comment: The link you provided does not work (404). The command in powershell directs me to https://manage.windowsazure.com/publishsettings/index?client=powershell&code=<code omitted>

Comment: Version of PowerShell is PS C:\> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
4      0      -1     -1

Comment: azure-cli version is at 0.7.5

Answer (score 0):

I encourage you to file a technical support ticket. In order to do so, you can:

- log in to the Azure Portal (i.e. https://manage.windowsazure.com/)
- click on your username on the upper right hand side
- click on "Contact Microsoft Support"